# Odroid XU4 with Yocto and GUI (gtk+3 error wayland-egl not found)

Tags: yocto, odroid

I am trying to build odroid-x11-image on thud.

This is my local.conf:

```
MACHINE ??= "odroid-xu4"

DISTRO ?= "poky"

PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_ipk"

USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " opencv boost"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks x11-base tools-debug splash ssh-server-dropbear package-management"
```

And here is my bblayers

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  poky/meta \
  poky/meta-poky \
  poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \
  meta-python \
  meta-odroid \
  meta-odroid/meta-odroid-extras \
  "
```

All I'm getting is an error on gtk+3 `No package 'wayland-egl' found`. Any idea or how to debug this? mali provides libwayland-egl, so that's normal it is not found...

Comment: which recipes in those layers are needed? I don't see why I would need qt to be able to use gtk+3...

Comment: This is probably related to last years change where wayland-egl moved from mesa to wayland (see https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2018-April/037767.html). Gtk is expecting to find the wayland-egl pkg-config file but apparently nothing is providing it when you build with mali... normally that and the .so file would now be provided by wayland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in a commit removing `${D}/${libdir}/pkgconfig/wayland-egl.pc`.

It should be corrected in future versions, https://github.com/akuster/meta-odroid/commit/b8fde89b77e0ebc98f74d1f2159fc54065babe6d